# Different package size of the same component

Tags: eaglecad

I am trying to create different package of the same component(grid size), with same pins. Thought that **package variant** is what I need. However it looks like I can't have same package with different variant names. Those are referring to the same package. If I change size of one variant, another is also changed. Now I am confused about **variant**.

Update:

one more attempt to explain question. As far as I understood variant is applicable for each unique package. So I created two identical packages, then gave unique variants to each.

[image]

My expectation was that variant will make my package unique and I could have different size of part in each package variant. But it looks like variant is just label and package itself should be unique. In other words if I want to create two packages with little difference of the same device, then I have to create two different packages. I really don't see the use of variant, at least within my subject.

Answer (score 4):

Each variant has to have a unique name.  The first variant is usually named "" (empty string).  You need to enter the names for the subsequent variants.

[image]

[image]

Screenshots from Eagle 6.3.0

Comment: Variant is just label for packages of the same device. Package name should be unique for the same device. To create different package sizecof the same device I have to create new package and label it accordingly as variant. It is not like I can create 3 packages with the same name and each having different variant, thus defining different package dimensions for each. Correct?

Comment: @Pablo  I'm not entirely clear what you have in mind.  AFAIK, Eagle doesn't have parametrization.  Each package is a separate entry with a unique name (at least, within one library).  A device is a combination of symbols (one or more) with packages (one or more).  Try to visualize a many-to-many relationship between symbols and packages.  The notion of the *package variant* exists only inside of a device.

Comment: see original message for another attempt to explain my question. Basically it comes to question - what is variant and whether I can use it within subject.

Comment: Still not clear what you want to do.  Perhaps if you explain what sort of differences you are trying to accomodate, people could recommend a course of action.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Distance between pins and diameter. The difference can be any, my question is rather conceptual, to understand what is "variant" and whether it's the tool to use for making different packages for the same device.

Comment: You need to make two different and uniquely named package footprints then, or identify existing ones which are suitable (footprints don't have to be part specific).  After you have done that, you can make two named variants within the device, each using a different footprint and its own mapping of schematic pins to footprint pins.

Comment: So again, variant is just way to label unique packages. Originally I thought the combination of variant and package footprint can make package itself unique, but now I understand variant is only for labeling.